# Given a Serre fibration between manifolds, how ugly can it be?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fibration

A Serre fibration is clearly defined with motivation from homotopy theory, but we can consider smooth versions $f\colon M\to N$ in the category of (finite-dimensional, paracompact etc) smooth manifolds, namely any smooth homotopy $H\colon I^n\times I \to N$ and smooth map $I^n\times\lbrace0\rbrace \to M$ lifting $H(-,0)$, there is a smooth lift of $H$ to $M$. For $N$ connected and $M$ non-empty, it is necessarily surjective.

Clearly smooth fibre bundles are Serre fibrations, but arbitrary surjective submersions are not (for example: $[0,\frac{2}{3})\coprod (\frac{1}{3},1] \to [0,1]$). However, I have reasons to consider fibrations with connected fibre.

I have a rough sketch of a proof in my head that smooth Serre fibrations are not far off being submersions, but that may just be the result of an overactive imagination.

I'd like to know what's the ugliest that a smooth Serre fibration with connected fibres can be. Single examples are welcome, as are characterisation theorem.

Secondly, what sort of fibres do we get? (Clearly they just might not be manifolds)

Conversely, what nice properties are smooth Serre fibrations with connected fibres guaranteed to have?

Comment: If I understand what you mean by a smooth fibration, then certainly such a map is always a submersion. 



Comment: I thought so, since we should be able to lift charts--or at least, cubes in the interior of charts--inductively.

Comment: Sorry, is there any reference where I can find a proof of the fact that every smooth Serre fibration is a submersion?

Comment: @D1811994 sorry, I don't know one, and I haven't though about this for a long time.

Comment: Don't worry. I already have one :)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2290761/223002) is a proof that smooth Serre fibrations are submersions. The question was inspired in part by this one.

Comment: By "smooth fibre bundles are Serre fibrations" you mean smooth fibre bundles are smooth serre fibrations in the sense you defined in first paragraph? Is it straight forward? Is the notion of smooth Serre fibration mentioned anywhere else? Does the same holds for Hurewicz fibrations (smooth set up)..

Comment: "smooth fibre bundles are smooth serre fibrations in the sense you defined in first paragraph?" <--- yes, and yes. Maybe to the third question, and for the fourth: yes, if you assume manifolds are paracompact and always Hausdorff (there are fin. dim. counterexamples, but people usually take these in the definition). For the infinite-dimensional setting where one might not have paracompactness (for instance, non-Fréchet, locally convex manifolds), then you need to assume the fibre bundle is [numerable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/numerable+bundle).

Comment: @DavidRoberts Oh. Thank you... Can you suggest some reference for this "smooth" versions of fibrations... thanks

Comment: Not really. The proof is the same, but with spaces replaced everywhere with manifolds and smooth maps. The only worry is maybe what a smooth function on a manifold with corners (i.e. $[0,1]^n$) looks like, but this is a non-issue. You can assume smooth in the interior such that all derivatives extend continuously to the boundary.